# ValueError: I/O operation on closed file but the syntax in another area of my code is the same and works correctly to save the file

Tags: python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

When attempting to save the updated excel workbook, an error occurs: ValueError: I/O operation on closed file. I have a similar block of code almost identical to this one which works properly and saves the changes to the excel workbook without issue using the same syntax. So I am not sure where the error is occurring.

```
#Prepares AUDIT RAW data to be copied into FIPA report from other workbooks
print("Audit Raw Data filepath aka name (Path 3):", glob.glob('v_cr_amp_dcp_audit_monitoring_*.csv')) #Test to check if filepath is correctly pulled
path3 = glob.glob('v_cr_amp_dcp_audit_monitoring_*.csv') #Sets path for AUDIT RAW data
path3 = ''.join(path3) #converts object from list to string
print("Audit Raw Data filepath aka name(Path 3):",path3)

print()

print("FILE CONVERSION!!!!!!!!")
#CONVERT CSV TO EXCEL
import pandas as pd
df_new = pd.read_csv(path3) # Reading the csv file
# saving xlsx file
GFG = pd.ExcelWriter('v_cr_amp_dcp_audit_monitoring_.xlsx')
df_new.to_excel(GFG, index=False)
print("csv to excel file path and name (path 3):", path3)
GFG.save()
print("FILE CONVERSION!!!!!!!!!")

print()
path3 = glob.glob("v_cr_amp*.xlsx")#Sets path for AUDIT RAW data after conversion
path3 = ''.join(path3)#converts object from list to string
workbook3 = openpyxl.load_workbook(path3) #Opens the AUDIT RAW workbook
sheetnames3 = workbook3.sheetnames #assigns variable to sheetname dictionary object
print("Audit Raw Data sheetnames:", sheetnames3) #Testing sheet name function
#Prepare target sheet (Audit raw) and source sheet (v_cr_amp_dcp_audit_monitoring...xlsx)
wb_target = workbook #Designates workbook where the data will move to
print("workbook target sheetnames:", wb_target.sheetnames)
target_sheet = wb_target['Audit Raw'] #Designates worksheet where the data will move to
wb_source = workbook3 #Designates workbook where the data will move from
print("workbook source sheetnames:", wb_source.sheetnames)
source_sheet = wb_source['Sheet1'] #Designates worksheet where the data will move from
copy_sheet(workbook3['Sheet1'], workbook['Audit Raw']) #Invokes copy_sheet() definition to copy data into FIPA report raw tab
path = './Test_Audit_Raw.xlsx'
workbook = wb_target
workbook.save(path)
```

ERROR NOTIFICATION

```
2845 
   2846     try:
-> 2847         fp.seek(0)
   2848     except (AttributeError, io.UnsupportedOperation):
   2849         fp = io.BytesIO(fp.read())

ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

Comment: where is fp in your code other than fp.seek(0) ???

Comment: I suspect the problem could be related to images. Please include the full traceback.